# php use <div> for json

Tags: javascript, php, css, json

In my PHP I have a line of JSON:

```
 echo '"jsoncaption":"'.$xxx.' '.$yyy.' <br /> ('.$zzz.')",';
```

I want to have the text `line-height: 110%;`, so I do this:

```
echo '<div style=\'line-height: 110%;\'>';
echo '"jsoncaption":"'.$xxx.' '.$yyy.' <br /> ('.$zzz.')",';
echo '</div>';
```

But this causes an an error in my JS console!

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 55

Without the `<div>` everything works, but I want to use `line-height`.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Whatever your goal is, I don't get it, but I would always suggest to use the `json_encode` function from PHP. to convert things to json, instead of writing it like you.

Comment: Wrap the div code between " " again, since without it's invalid JSON. You'll have to send it as a string if you want it to be JSON.

Comment: JSON has a strict format and from the three lines above it looks like you're not adhering to them. The middle line is `property: value` which would exist inside of an object, so I would expect to see either `{` and `}` on the first and last lines or additional `property: value` pairs. Instead you've inserted regular HTML into what should be object notation.

Comment: Resolved by user3691763. Thanks all

Comment: @Shilly wouldn't they also have to make the `<div>` portions a property of an object or the value of a property? Right now just adding double quotes wouldn't work would it?

Comment: Definately. I assumed this is just a snippet of a bigger manual JSON text and that needing a key for it is self-evident. Adding the quotes makes the div part a valid string so it resolves the 'Unexpected token' error.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"jsoncaption":"' . '<div style=\'line-height: 110%;\'>' . $xxx .' '.$yyy.' <br /> ('.$zzz.')</div>",';
```

What did I do?

This would be a more detailed script:

```
$content = $xxx.' '.$yyy.' <br /> ('.$zzz.')';
$wrapped_content = '<div style=\'line-height: 110%;\'>' . $content . "</div>";
echo '"jsoncaption":"' . $wrapped_content . '",';
```

EDIT: Untested of course, maybe some quotation marks are wrong...

Comment: Thanks :) Would you mind marking the answer as correct? :)

Comment: And .... More complicated . If I want to use a different size for the $zzz , do u have an idea ? ps : Yes of course for marking answer correct

Comment: `$zzz = "<div style='font-size: 8px'>" . $zzz . "</div>";` on top of all

Comment: Ok i will try this ! Thanks !!

Comment: You're welcome, but maybe you want to move the brackets into my last code snippet and remove it from the first one.